# Trouble setting a players ID and Username through callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, callback

With an HTML5 game I am developing at the moment, I get the player's username and ID through a token sent in by the client which are all stored in a database. Everything was working perfectly up until I had to actually set the values for the player.

I've been searching all over the internet for similar problems that I am facing, and have come up with nothing. I am not sure if this is a variable scope problem or if I am taking the wrong approach to doing this.

Anyways, here's both the socket.player and getUserSession function

```js
var newUserID;
var newUsersName;
socket.player = {
    id: newUserID,
    x: randomInt(100,400),
    y: randomInt(100,400),
    username: newUsersName
}
```

```js
function getUserSession(sessionKey, callback){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM game_sessions WHERE unique_key=? AND still_active=?";
    var stillActive = 1;
    var returnData = [];
    db.query(sql, [sessionKey, stillActive], function(err, result){
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }

        var numFound = result.length;
        if (numFound == 1) {
            //session was found
            var userID = result[0].user_id;
            returnData.push(result[0].user_id);

            var sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";
            db.query(sql2, [userID], function(err, result){
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                }
                var uName = result[0].username;
                returnData.push(result[0].username);
                return callback(returnData);
            });

        }

    });

}
```

And the callback function:

```
getUserSession(data.token, function(result){
    newUserID = result[0];
    newUsersName = result[1];
    socket.broadcast.emit('newclient',socket.player);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function sqlQuery(sql, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

function getUserSession(sessionKey, callback){
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM game_sessions WHERE unique_key=? AND still_active=?";
    const stillActive = 1;
    let returnData = [];

    try {
        return sqlQuery(sql, [sessionKey, stillActive])
            .then(result => {
                if (result.length === 1) {
                    //session was found
                    const userID = result[0].user_id;
                    returnData.push(result[0].user_id);

                    const sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";
                    return sqlQuery(sql2, [userID])
                        .then(result => {
                            const uName = result[0].username;
                            returnData.push(result[0].username);
                            return callback(returnData);
                        })
                }
            })
    } catch (err) {
        //handle err
    }
}
```

Edit: if the callback function being passed in is an aync function, you'll probably need to modify the above snippet to await it.